# Looking for a Py2neo fork

Tags: python, neo4j, graph-databases, py2neo

Unfortunately due to some internal politics within neo4j, the py2neo project is now EOL and was deleted from pypi. See this [twitter thread](https://twitter.com/technige/status/1659452229659643906).

Is there anyone who might have forked the GitHub repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see updates here https://community.neo4j.com/t/farewell-py2neo-what-happens-now/64419

Copied from Above link,

- https://github.com/overhangio/py2neo,
- https://github.com/SarLecobee/py2neo,
- https://github.com/neo4j-field/py2neo,

And One can see here as well, https://www.reddit.com/r/Neo4j/comments/174jl66/py2neo_no_longer_available/

Comment: Thank you. This is definitely helpful!!!

Comment: The official fork is now at https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/py2neo
`py2neo` is back on pypi, and documentation will be available soon.
We'll continue to update the thread at community.neo4j.com

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/memgraph/gqlalchemy is also an Object Graph Mapper (equivalent to the `py2neo`) maintained by memgraph.com. It's compatible with py2neo, but maybe an option is to migrate because the project will be maintained.

DISCLAIMER: I'm the co-founder and CTO of Memgraph

Comment: Thank you. It works on Neo4j right?

Comment: Yes, it does. GQLAlchemy supports Memgraph and Neo4j. The documentation is located at https://memgraph.github.io/gqlalchemy/